# 'Fall is here' and '<he> has gone full pumpkin'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I found [this sentence](http://redd.it/2jy69f):

> Fall is here, which means my cat has gone full pumpkin.

I can't understand what it means.

> Fall is here...

Does it mean something from where you can fall down?

> ...has gone full pumpkin.

I think *has gone* means that cat looks like full pumpkin, but in this case why does he looks like that only because he is located in the place where he can fall down?

Could you explain the meaning of this sentance?

Comment: 99% of the time, I think you'll find that _fall is here_ means _autumn is here_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've [found the sentence at reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/2jy6e2/fall_is_here_which_means_my_cat_has_gone_full/). It goes with a picture of a cat that looks like a pumpkin.

**Fall** here means **autumn**, the time of the year when pumpkins become ripe and assume their characteristic shape and color.

Hence, the sentence means that with the arrival of autumn the cat started looking very much ("full") like a pumpkin.

[image]

Note that there's no article before *Fall*: articles are usually omitted when we refer to seasons generally, as distinct from referring to a particular part of a particular year. ([Quirk et al., 5.47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language))

Had the author meant to say that there's a place from which someone could fall, he would have wrote:

> **A** fall is here. (a bit awkward sentence)
>   There's **a** rather steep fall beyond that ledge. (more like it)

Comment: Very good answer! +1 However, it may also mean the cat is looking cute. The word *pumpkin* is also used as a term of endearment for someone who is small and cute! :)

Comment: +1 for finding the context. I thought this was a very unusual sentence until I saw the accompanying picture!

Answer (score 5):

**Fall** is the (chiefly North American name for the) season also known as *autumn*. Pumpkins are associated with fall, especially in their uses in Halloween, Thanksgiving, pumpkin pie, and pumpkin-flavored everything.

[image: Brace yourselves / pumpkin flavored everything is coming] [image: orange cat]

**"[Go/gone] full x"** likely comes from the ["go full retard"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/full-retard) meme (similar meanings are found in "full-blown" or "full on"), and means roughly, "to become very similar to x" (note that using "retard" like this is somewhat offensive, and should not be said in polite conversation). In this case, it means that the cat greatly resembles a pumpkin with his round shape and orange fur. His cat may have looked like that before, but his humorous claim appears to be that his cat turned into a pumpkin for fall. You might restate it as:

> Autumn is here, which means my cat has turned into a pumpkin. or
>   Autumn is here, and my cat looks a lot like a pumpkin.

Comment: I disagree about the origin of `gone full x` it is more of a normal metaphor than anything else.

Comment: @x-x I couldn't find a better definition, source, or origin for it...I'd like to agree with you, but I figured pointing to something else that's "go full" would help clarify. If you have a better reference, let me know!

Comment: @x-x - Tim never says anything about "metaphor" in this answer. I think _"Gone full X" means roughly, "to become very similar to x"_ is actually a pretty good way of describing it, as in [Taylor Swift Has Gone Full Cat Lady](http://theblemish.com/2014/10/taylor-swift-gone-full-cat-lady/) or [Glenn Beck Has Gone Full Blown Televangelist](http://www.newscorpse.com/ncWP/?p=1492). I'd like to also mention to our learners that "gone full retard" may be considered rude or offensive language; the word "retard" (or just "tard" as slang) may offend some, particularly if you don't know them well.

Comment: @J.R. it may not be a metaphor but it is still a *kind of (my vocabulary maybe wrong)* idiomatic expression.

Comment: @x-x - Actually, I apologize; I misread your original comment. I thought you were disagreeing with Tim's claim of it being a metaphor (I missed the word "it", and thought you said: _I disagree [that] the origin of 'gone full x' is more of a normal metaphor than anything else_. I see now you meant something different. _Mea culpa_.